# MySQL JSON object insert

Tags: mysql, sql, json, function, insert

I have the following JSON:

```
 {
    "params" : {
        "A" : 200.5,
        "B" : 70.2
    }
 }
```

And the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `params` (
   `param` varchar(255),
   `value` float
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Is there a way to make mysql function with one insert query without using "while do" directly to insert all the parameters into table like this:

```
 -------+-------
| param | value |
|-------+-------|
|     A |  200.5|
|     B |   70.2|
 ---------------
```

Comment: You cannot do this directly in MySql. Only you can store complete Json in one tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `json_keys()` to dynamically extract the keys from the json subobject as a json array, and then use `json_table()` to turn it to rows. You can then extract the values.

Consider:

```
insert into `params`
with t as (select '{"params": { "A": 200.5, "B": 70.2 } }' js)
select x.k, json_extract(js, concat('$.params.', x.k)) v
from 
    t
    cross join json_table(
        json_keys(js->"$.params"),
        "$[*]" columns(k varchar(255) path "$")
    ) as x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8fb1c8cea704ec8d9fc5629c2c884912)**

Content of the table after running the query:

```
param | value
:---- | ----:
A     | 200.5
B     |  70.2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can insert multiple rows with a single query using insert into. we need to construct this query using your JSON object

```
INSERT INTO params(param,value)
VALUES('A',200.5), ('B', 70.2);
```